# Jest Cannot read property 'default' of undefined during test

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, create-react-app

I am new in testing and I created a react app via Create-React-App and I am just trying to run a test.

My test is as simple as that

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { App } from '../containers';

it('renders without crashing', () => {
  const div = document.createElement('div');
  expect(3).toBe(3)
});
```

I want to mention that when I run it without **Import App** it runs succesfully.
But otherwise the following error arises.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'default' of undefined

  at Object.get [as EmailSender] (src/routes/index.js:65:25)
  at Object.EmailSender (src/index.js:37:22)
  at Object.<anonymous> (src/functions/getSettingsDataFromStore.js:1:1)
  at Object.<anonymous> (src/routes/register/RegisterDescription.js:9:1)
  at Object.<anonymous> (src/routes/index.js:6:1)
  at Object.<anonymous> (src/functions/getAvailableRoutes.js:4:1)
  at Object.<anonymous> (src/components/Navbar.js:4:1)
  at Object.<anonymous> (src/components/index.js:6:1)
  at Object.<anonymous> (src/containers/App.js:4:1)
  at Object.<anonymous> (src/containers/index.js:1:1)
  at Object.<anonymous> (src/tests/App.test.js:3:1)
```

Here is my package.json file.

```
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.8",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.5.0",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.1.3",
    "@material-ui/core": "^3.1.2",
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "cors": "^2.8.4",
    "dotenv": "^5.0.1",
    "email-validator": "^2.0.4",
    "eosjs": "^16.0.9",
    "google-maps-react": "^2.0.2",
    "history": "^4.7.2",
    "ipfs-http-client": "^28.1.1",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "jwt-decode": "^2.2.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.9.3",
    "npm": "^6.4.1",
    "nstall": "^0.2.0",
    "object-assign": "^4.1.1",
    "postcss-flexbugs-fixes": "^3.3.0",
    "postcss-loader": "^2.1.6",
    "promise": "^8.0.1",
    "qrcode.react": "^0.8.0",
    "query-string": "^6.1.0",
    "rc-steps": "^3.3.0",
    "rc-time-picker": "^3.3.1",
    "react": "^16.3.2",
    "react-app": "^1.1.2",
    "react-bootstrap-datetimerangepicker-edited": "^2.0.8",
    "react-bootstrap-table": "^4.3.1",
    "react-bootstrap-table-next": "^1.4.1",
    "react-datepicker": "^2.4.0",
    "react-dev-utils": "^5.0.2",
    "react-dnd": "^2.6.0",
    "react-dnd-html5-backend": "^2.6.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.3.2",
    "react-dropdown": "^1.4.2",
    "react-error-overlay": "^4.0.1",
    "react-facebook-login": "^4.1.1",
    "react-google-login": "^5.0.0",
    "react-google-recaptcha": "^1.0.5",
    "react-helmet": "^5.2.0",
    "react-jss": "^8.6.1",
    "react-modal": "^3.6.1",
    "react-password-strength": "^2.4.0",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.7",
    "react-router": "^4.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
    "react-scripts": "3.0.0",
    "react-select": "^1.2.1",
    "react-show-more": "^2.0.0",
    "react-tagsinput": "^3.19.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "^16.8.6",
    "reactstrap": "^6.0.1",
    "sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
    "socket.io": "^2.1.1",
    "style-loader": "^0.21.0",
    "url-loader": "^1.1.1",
    "uuid": "^3.3.2",
    "validator": "^10.7.1",
    "whatwg-fetch": "^2.0.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "fix": "eslint --fix src"
  },
  "jest": {
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "src/**/*.{js,jsx}",
      "!**/node_modules/**"
    ]
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "css-loader": "^2.1.1",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^16.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.11.0",
    "eslint-plugin-node": "^6.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^3.7.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.7.0",
    "eslint-plugin-standard": "^3.0.1",
    "img-loader": "^3.0.0",
    "stylelint-config-standard": "^18.2.0"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

I have spend more than 8 hours and I have not find a solution. Every idea would be welcomed. Thank you in advance.

EDIT: 
Here is the routes/index.js

```
export { default as NoMatch } from './NoMatch';
export { default as Logout } from './Logout';
export { default as Explore } from './Explore';
export { default as Login } from './Login';
export { default as RegisterRequired } from './register/RegisterRequired';
export { default as RegisterDescription } from './register/RegisterDescription';
export { default as RegisterBusinessOffers } from './register/RegisterBusinessOffers';
export { default as RegisterBasicInfos } from './register/RegisterBasicInfos';
export { default as RegisterQuestions } from './register/RegisterQuestions';
export { default as EmailSender } from './register/EmailSender';
export { default as EmailVerification } from './register/EmailVerification';
export { default as VerifyYourAccount } from './register/VerifyYourAccount';
export { default as General } from './settings/General';
export { default as Policy } from './Policy';
export { default as BasicInfos } from './settings/BasicInfos';
export { default as BusinessOffers } from './settings/BusinessOffers';
export { default as Description } from './settings/Description';
export { default as Security } from './settings/Security';
export { default as ForgotYourPassword } from './login/ForgotYourPassword';
export { default as ResetPassword } from './login/ResetPassword';
```

and here is the App.js as you want

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Route, Switch } from 'react-router';
import { Helmet } from 'react-helmet';
import {
  Header,
  PrivateRoutes,
  Navbar,
  Footer} from '../components';
import ...

...

class App extends Component {
  static defaultProps = {
    className: 'app container-fluid p-0 row no-gutters d-flex',
  }

  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);

    }


  render() {

    if (!this.state.isVerified)
    {
      return (
          <div className="all_wrapper">

         <Header />
         <div className="wrapper">
         <main className={className}>

          <Helmet titleTemplate="%s | ComeTogether" defaultTitle="ComeTogether" />

          <div className="flex-fill">
            <Navbar/>
            <Scene>
              <Switch location={location}>
                <Route
                    component={General}
                    path="/settings/general"
                    exact
                />
                <Route
                    component= {Security}
                    path="/settings/security"
                    exact
                />
                <Route
                  component={VerifyYourAccount}
                />
              </Switch>
              <Footer />
            </Scene>
          </div>

        </main>
      </div>
          </div>
      );
    }else if((!Auth.getProfile().hasOwnProperty("isVenue") && !Auth.getProfile().hasOwnProperty("isServiceProvider")) || (store.getState().flags.completeProfile === true)){
      return (
                <Switch location={location}>
                  <Route
                    component= {RegisterQuestions}
                    path="/register/questions"
                    exact
                  />
                  <Route
                    component= {RegisterBasicInfos}
                    path="/register/basicinfos"
                    exact
                  />
                  <Route
                    component= {RegisterDescription}
                    path="/register/description"
                    exact
                  />
                  <Route
                    component= {RegisterBusinessOffers}
                    path="/register/businessOffers"
                    exact
                  />
                  <Route
                    component= {RegisterQuestions}
                  />
                </Switch>
              );
    }else {
      return (
      <div className="all_wrapper">
         <Header />
         <div className="wrapper">
           <main className={className}>

            <Helmet titleTemplate="%s | ComeTogether" defaultTitle="ComeTogether" />

            <div className="flex-fill">
              <Navbar/>
              <Scene>
                {getAvailableRoutes(location)}
                <Footer />
              </Scene>
            </div>

        </main>
        </div>
    </div>
      );
    }
  }
}

export default PrivateRoutes(App);
```

and the EmailSender.js file

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { Helmet } from 'react-helmet';
import "../../styles/register/emailSenderAndVerification.scss";
import {Link} from "react-router-dom";


class EmailSender extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
        }
        this.redirect = this.redirect.bind(this);
    }

    redirect(){
      this.props.history.push('./login')
    }


    render() {
      var title = "";
      var helmetTitle ="";
      if(window.location.pathname.toLowerCase() === "/emailsender")
      {
        title = "Email Verification"
        helmetTitle = "Register | ComeTogether"
      }else if(window.location.pathname.toLowerCase() === "/resetpassemail")
      {
        title = "Reset Your Password"
        helmetTitle = "Reset | ComeTogether"
      }
    return(
       <div className="container-fluid" id="registration">
          <Helmet>
           <title>{helmetTitle}</title>
          </Helmet>
        <div className = "logoAndRegisterBtn">
            <Link to="/">
                <div className="registration_logo">
                    <img className="comeTogetherLogoLoginAndRegister" alt="" src="/images/ALL LOGOS CT-04.png" />
                </div>
            </Link>

          <div className="emailSenderContainer">
            <div className="emailSenderLogoContainer">
              <img className="emailSenderLogo" alt="" src="images/CT LOGO TEXT-01-no shadow.png" onClick={this.redirect}/>
            </div>
            <div className="emailSenderMain">
              <div className="emailSenderMsgBoxTitle">
                <span> {title}</span>
              </div>
              <div className="emailSenderMsgBoxContent">
                We have send a confirmation email to your registered email address. <b>{localStorage.getItem("email")}</b>.
                <br/>
                Please follow the instructions in the email to continue.
              </div>

              <div className="emailSenderMsgBoxTip">
                <strong>If you haven't received the email, please try the following: </strong>
                <ul>
                  <li>Make sure the email address you provided is correct.</li>
                  <li>Check your spam or junk mail folders.</li>
                  <li>Make sure your email client is functioning normally.</li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default EmailSender;
```

Comment: Can you paste your code of App under '../containers'?

Comment: Starting with the error, can you also show us `src/routes/index.js` (the origin of the error, from the very first line of the stacktrace)

Comment: I just add the files you asked for.

Comment: The error seems from 'export { default as EmailSender } from './register/EmailSender', can you also show it?

Comment: I just did! But I test it in another app and it was ok.

Comment: Hey Nikos, did you solve this mistery?

Comment: Hello Mihey. The problem is that when I try to import a file from index.js (which contains lots of exports), the program tries to read all files into the index.js. You have to import explicit the file you want. In addition check if the file you want imports other files from index.js etc etc etc

Comment: @NikosChatzivasileiadis Would be useful if you could write a solution for the community. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Because you are testing or including a component (../containers/App) which may contain children components, it is suggested to test the basic rendering with shallow rendering in your unit test.

Shallow rendering lets you render a component “one level deep” and assert facts about what its render method returns, without worrying about the behavior of child components, which are not instantiated or rendered. This does not require a DOM.

To find out more, please check the document here: https://reactjs.org/docs/shallow-renderer.html

I suggest you look at Enzyme: https://airbnb.io/enzyme/ it works perfectly with Jest if you are testing React components such as rendering, state, event listeners, etc.

Comment: It doesnt help, because the problem arises from the import { App } from '../containers'; Thank you for your time by the way!